# Display InLine-Block elements with value margin and margin effact

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

If there are two elements with a value of Display InLine-Block

They are located next to each other on the same line

Then we gave one of them a margin top value

Or margin Bottom

Both elements are affected by the margin value

Why are the two elements affected by the margin value?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: _"Why are the two elements affected by the margin value?"_ - because giving one of them a margin, increases the height of the "line" they are both sitting on.